# Updating Profile - using metadata

Tags: webservices, metadata-api, profile, record-type

I needed to first create some Record Types for some custom objects using Metadata. After doing those, I was to upsert the records on those custom objects using the RecordTypeId.

I noticed one thing that one needs to set the visibility of the Record Types from Profile otherwise the Error comes - something like Invalide RecordTypeId for the User.

So, I have the flow of my application set from Java as

First create the Record Types, thereafter fetch the RecordTypeID and then upsert the records on the custom object I need to target.

So, I need to update the Profile using Metadata API itself to set the visibility of Record Types as:

```
ProfileRecordTypeVisibility[] prtv = new ProfileRecordTypeVisibility[recordTypes.size()];
prtv[0] = new ProfileRecordTypeVisibility();
prtv[0].setRecordType("abc");
prtv[0].setDefault(true);
prtv[0].setVisible(true);

Profile pr = new Profile();
pr.setRecordTypeVisibilities(prtv);
UpdateMetadata ut = new UpdateMetadata();
pr.setFullName("System_Administrator");
ut.setMetadata(pr);
```

So, I'm getting the Error like

```
com.sforce.ws.SoapFaultException: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY: In field: fullName - no Profile named System_Administrator found.
```

I have even tried System Administrator, Profile, Profile.System_Administrator but none worked for me.

The Salesforce doc says for the Profile object's fullName field: `It must be specified when creating, updating, or deleting`.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong or is there anything else I can go for.

Thanks

Comment: I logged in to my org via https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php and used the Metadata Query feature to list the profiles and I don't see System Administrator. Can you perform this action via the UI out of interest? Also have you tried doing this on a custom profile?

Answer (score 8):

I have found the solution by using fullName **Admin** which is got by querying Profile Object using listMetadata() method of MetadataConnection. The list of fullName of Standard Profiles then returned are as follows:

```
SolutionManager
Customer Portal Manager Standard
StandardAul
Standard
Chatter Free User
Chatter External User
ContractManager
Customer Portal Manager Custom
Silver Partner User
Chatter Moderator User
Custom%3A Sales Profile
Partner App Subscription
Admin
Force%2Ecom - Free User
MarketingProfile
Custom%3A Marketing Profile
HighVolumePortal
Custom%3A Support Profile
Force%2Ecom - App Subscription User
Gold Partner User
PlatformPortal
ReadOnly
```

Thanks to Andrew who has given this idea.

Comment: Here's the URL to pull this list that equates to the Profile.fullName property: https://workbench.developerforce.com/metadataDescribeAndList.php?type=Profile